Problem positioning InfLineLabel in pyqtgraph
I am using a horizontal line as follows in pyqtgraph. If I set the position of the label to 0.05, then it hugs the y axis with the default graph size. However, if I resize the graph there is an offset. Setting the label position to 0 doesn't work as part of the label gets cut off. Is there a way to position the label directly adjacent to the y axis regardless of the graph size?
import sys
import numpy as np
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
import pyqtgraph as pg

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
win = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget(show=True, title="y = exp(x) with Movable Line")
plot = win.addPlot(title="y = exp(x) with Movable Line")
x = np.linspace(-2, 2, 1000)
y = np.exp(x)
plot.plot(x, y, pen='b')

# Create a movable infinite horizontal line with a label that updates based on y-position
h_line = pg.InfiniteLine(pos=1.0, angle=0, movable=True)
plot.addItem(h_line)
h_line.label = pg.InfLineLabel(h_line, text=f"y = {h_line.value():.2f}", position=0.05, color='r', fill=(255, 255, 255, 255))

def update_label():
    h_line.label.setText(f"y = {h_line.value():.2f}")

h_line.sigPositionChanged.connect(update_label)
sys.exit(app.exec_())


Pyqtgraph is positioning InfiniteLabel to the center of InfiniteLine. Tha'ts why setting position = 0 is cutting half of the label out. So, basically you need to add label_width / 2 to the infinite label position calculation. After that label should be nicely aligned with Y axis.
Here is example code you can use:
import sys
import numpy as np
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
import pyqtgraph as pg


class InfLabel(pg.InfLineLabel):

    def updatePosition(self):
        # update text position to relative view location along line
        self._endpoints = (None, None)
        pt1, pt2 = self.getEndpoints()
        if pt1 is None:
            return
        pt = pt2 * self.orthoPos + pt1 * (1 - self.orthoPos)

        half_label_width = self.mapRectToParent(self.boundingRect()).width() / 2
        pt.setX(pt.x() + half_label_width)

        self.setPos(pt)

        # update anchor to keep text visible as it nears the view box edge
        vr = self.line.viewRect()
        if vr is not None:
            self.setAnchor(self.anchors[0 if vr.center().y() < 0 else 1])


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
win = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget(show=True, title="y = exp(x) with Movable Line")
plot = win.addPlot(title="y = exp(x) with Movable Line")
x = np.linspace(-2, 2, 1000)
y = np.exp(x)
plot.plot(x, y, pen='b')

# Create a movable infinite horizontal line with a label that updates based on y-position
h_line = pg.InfiniteLine(pos=1.0, angle=0, movable=True)
plot.addItem(h_line)
h_line.label = InfLabel(h_line, text=f"y = {h_line.value():.2f}", position=0, color='r', fill=(255, 255, 255, 255))


def update_label():
    h_line.label.setText(f"y = {h_line.value():.2f}")
    h_line.label.updatePosition()


h_line.sigPositionChanged.connect(update_label)
sys.exit(app.exec_())


